# Inserting an R variable into a string

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I'm trying to produce multiple charts and figures using a for loop in R.

I'm writing the files like this:

```
for(i in 1:10){
png("C:/Users/Username/Documents/FileName.png", height = 8, width = 14, units = 'in', res = 350)
g <- ggplot(df)
dev.off()
print(g)
}
```

However, I'm pretty sure if I try to execute this code, I'm going to end up with either 1 "FileName.png" or "FileName.png", "FileName(1).png", etc. Is there a way that I can introduce a variable inside the `png()` string that would depend on the index?

Answer (score 1):

You e.g. do the following:

```
base_name <- "C:/Users/Username/Documents/"
for(i in 1:3){
  q <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
  out_path <- sprintf("%s/filename%s.png", base_name, i)
  ggsave(out_path, q, "png")
}
```

which gives you `filename1.png` - `filename3.png` in documents

If you prefer working with `png(...)` just use the out path in that call.